# Prompt the user for a String. Show the text along with the first and last character

Tags: java, string, char

I am having trouble with figuring out how to identify the last letter of the string input. I'm not sure if I should be using a char[] instead of a string. Should I use a char for the first and last letter or a String?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter some text");
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You entered: " + input);

    if (input.length() == 1) {
        char firstLetter = input.charAt(0);
        firstLetter = Character.toLowerCase(firstLetter);

        if (firstLetter == 'U' || firstLetter == 'S' || firstLetter == 'b' || firstLetter == 'B'
                || firstLetter == 'x') {
            System.out.println("First letter: " + firstLetter);
        }

        if (firstLetter == 'a' || firstLetter == 't' || firstLetter == 'x') {
            System.out.println("Last letter: " + firstLetter);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `firstLetter = Character.toLowerCase(firstLetter);` Hint: it is not going to be `U` or `S` or `B`

Comment: Either a char or a string is perfectly ok. For char `input.charAt(0);` `input.charAt(input.length()-1);` or for string `first = input.substring(0, 1);` `last = input.substring(input.length()-1);` Just make sure you stick with one or the other so that you can properly compare them in your `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Enter a string: \n");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    if (input.length() > 0) {
        System.out.println("You entered: " + input);
        System.out.println("Last charcter: " + input.charAt(0));
        System.out.println("Last charcter: " + input.charAt(input.length() - 1));
    }
    scanner.close();

}
```